# Aggregate and count in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have PostgreSQL table with some columns group by Area column. I want to do aggregation by the column Application and then calculate number of each item.

I tried

```
SELECT app.area, array_agg(app.application)
FROM applications as app GROUP BY app.area
```

and have got the list of applications:

```
Item1,Item2,Item1,Item3,Item1
```

How can I get next:

```
Item1: 3
Item2: 1
Item3: 1
```

Comment: `count(*) and then group by`

Comment: does not seem like mysql, I found array_agg in PostgreSQL

Comment: I can't group by applications, becouse I use this Query in cartoDB and should group only by area for my visualization

Comment: Then get those and count them in your code.. But it seems grouping is possible by multiple columns as seen it examples - http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/joining_data.html

Comment: Your question seems unclear, add some relevant data and exact sample output

Comment: does `Item1,Item2,Item1,Item3,Item1` is the sample output of this `array_agg(app.application)` function in the given select  ?

Comment: Yes, I have got this string Item1,Item2,Item1,Item3,Item1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SQL COUNT() function.

You can get some info about it and some examples here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp

Comment: COUNT fuction give me only general number of all application. I can't group by application in my case